# React-Native passing data from child to parent error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting an error when I am trying to set the state on a parent component from a child, it says `getTimeToReadIdeea is not a function`.

I have the following:

parent class component:

```
getTimeToReadIdeea = time => {
  this.setState({ timeToReadInsightId: time });
};
....//other code
  render() {
...//other code
    <Card getTimeToReadIdeea={this.getTimeToReadIdeea} />
}
```

child functional component:

```
const child =({getTimeToReadIdeea}) => {
useEffect(() => {
    getTimeToReadIdeea(timeToReadInsight[insightId]);
  }, [isFocused]);

...//other code
}
```

The code looks good to me. I've done this hundred times before. I can't find out why.

Comment: Do you have like `const child` defined the child component? Or it just because of representation here? If not, maybe you can try with `const Card = ({getTimeToReadIdeea}) => { /* component code */ }` instead.

Comment: It's just for the representation here

Comment: Maybe it's better to post the real code for easier helping or like both of the components.

Answer (score 0):

So I was using my child component in multiple places.
The problem was I had to add a check in the useEffect,

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (simple || !getTimeToReadIdeea) {
      return;
    }

    getTimeToReadIdeea && getTimeToReadIdeea(timeToReadInsight[insightId]);
  }, [isFocused]);
```

This fixed my problem.